php cURL curl_exec returns false, stopping execution before initializing with errno 43 BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT
I send several curl requests from service A (running phpunit tests) to service B (api).
After a fixed amount of curl calls, the curl_exec function returns false with code 43 which means BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT.
The error always occurs at the same test in my set of tests. If I remove a test before the error hits, the error simply shifts forward to the next test that uses curl.
This looks like I am hitting a (hard) limit somethere, this is what I know:

From start to crash takes about 30 seconds, suggesting a timeout limit

I set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120
I set CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120
Set script max time set_time_limit(0) (infinite) in php


Since the test always occurs at the same spot, maybe a memory limit?

Increase memory_limit 128 => => 512 in php.ini and reboot server


The CURLOPT_VERBOSE information shows connections are reused

Set CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true
Add header 'Connection: close' to requests



None of these help me prevent the curl error, lets take a look at the verbose info of the request before the error and the info of the error.
The last successful curl before the error
* Host localhost:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: ::1
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80
> GET /user/2645f3b7-a187-47c0-95d3-0ab1696501eb/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
Connection: close
Authorization: Bearer: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJrZXlzIjp7lciJ9.JivFp5Rp6YcQ5KkcEp_7WiVB2SmIRdnXcsg86r3eGIE

* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 08 May 2024 12:28:43 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2u PHP/8.2.0 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.18 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.30.1
< X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.0
< Set-Cookie: _ssid=0qupDtygjuhsOEQyDYilnLSfcEymOUDKDwdTVXEyQqC68D3b8tkPH6-SCby2qcKB%2CsJU1%2C4vbk39hLbeT%2CWGgdh%2Ctn9C4SOerZ2YHh6VWIrsI3Br8X-Jyu1XCfsMk8Lu; expires=Wed, 15 May 2024 12:28:43 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Length: 1208
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
* Closing connection

With the following curlinfo
array(40) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(57) "http://localhost/user/2645f3b7-a187-47c0-95d3-0ab1696501eb/"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(16) "application/json"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(703)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(1.024873)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(5.2E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.000393)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.000602)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(44)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(114)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(111)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(42)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(114)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(44)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(1.024833)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(3) "::1"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(3) "::1"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(59910)
  ["http_version"]=>
  int(2)
  ["protocol"]=>
  int(1)
  ["ssl_verifyresult"]=>
  int(0)
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "HTTP"
  ["appconnect_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_time_us"]=>
  int(393)
  ["namelookup_time_us"]=>
  int(52)
  ["pretransfer_time_us"]=>
  int(602)
  ["redirect_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["starttransfer_time_us"]=>
  int(1024833)
  ["total_time_us"]=>
  int(1024873)
  ["effective_method"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["cainfo"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Then the error hits, no verbose information only curlinfo with no values
array(40) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(57) "http://localhost/role/ROLE-RKX0TRLT1QGF/"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(0)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(0)
  ["http_version"]=>
  int(0)
  ["protocol"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ssl_verifyresult"]=>
  int(0)
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["appconnect_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["namelookup_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["pretransfer_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["starttransfer_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time_us"]=>
  int(0)
  ["effective_method"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["cainfo"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Clearly curl is not even initialized and it crashes. The errno is set to 43 BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT but there is no way of figuring out what causes this. If I run only a subset of tests including the one that errors when running all tests, all works fine.
In case anyone has suggestions on how to figure out what is causing this, maybe some curl option I haven't heard of. Maybe the max connection count on the apache server which I assume are closed because of the CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE option and 'Connection: close' header.

Just a side note, could you just Mock the API? Is there a need to test the communication in local environment? When you mock the API responses, you don’t have to rely on other variables, just your code.

@Eduard You are right, this approach has more benefits than just preventing this error to happen. Also when testing starts as part of a CI/CD pipeline. Thanks for the suggestion, I will consider it!

As an alternative, if you're testing the system that you send requests to, you can do that in-process, though it requires a bit of (reusable!) scaffolding up front. In any case, code that works and then suddenly doesn't smells like a resource leak. Do you properly dispose of the cURL handles? Please, it would also help if you extracted and provided a [mcve].

BTW: If curl_init() fails and you don't detect that failure from the returnvalue, a subsequent call to curl_exec() using that returnvalue will fail as well. Further, if that's not the cause, can you tell whether the request was actually sent to the remote? It might be some kind of rate limiting kicking in.

You have stated "After a fixed amount of curl calls". So at the point of the last successful call, how many curl calls have been successful? This number may give a clue to where that hard limit is. Also, just in case, in this page there is a short post on how to debug curl_exec call (open the page and do find for the word 'debug' to get to the post): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

The error was created by curl version used at the time which was 8.1.2. If you are experiencing unexpected 43 BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT errors please update your curl. At the time of writing curl 8.7.1 does not produce this error.
